# How can I do this using Gradient Tool in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, gradient

I want to do that using gradient tool but things eventually go wrong< so what should I do ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the width of a stroke in the Stroke panel:

[image]

More info: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/stroke-object.html

Comment: I have already made a black stroke. I want the gradient to be inside that stroke.